# How can I access an unknown number of parameters passed on the stack for the function call?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, calling-convention

If I pass an unknown number of paramteres to the function (sort of like a printf), how do I know how far back I have to go to get all the parameters. At first I've though about saving the difference between the %rbp and %rsp to get the displacement, but that doesn't help since they are initialized at random at runtime from what I've seen

With the calling conventions, the first 6 arguments are passed in registers, so I have to push them on the stack once in the subroutine. The question is how do I get the remaining (n - 6) arguments from the stack, considering that the return address and the base pointer have been pushed on the stack in between the arguments. The function looks somewhat like this:

```
.data
#variables here

main:

push arg_n
push arg_n-1
...
movq $arg_2, %rsi
movq $arg_1, %rdi
call ft_function

ft_function:

push %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp

push %rdi
push %rsi
...
#Function code here
...
movq %rbp, %rsp
pop %rbp
ret
```

Comment: To access the arguments you need to know how many and what type there are. `printf`, for example, as you are surely aware, uses the format string to refer to the remaining variable arguments. There is nothing in the calling convention that would tell you this (except for `al` containing an upper limit on the xmm registers used).

Comment: The alternative to passing an argument that indicates the number and types of the rest of the arguments(as with printf) is to put a marker as the last argument. A common example is execl, which has an arbitrarily long list of arguments that are all of type char \*. The list is terminated with a null pointer of type char \*.

Comment: Would there be a way so just swap on the stack the arguments, as to have all the arguments and then the saved %rbp and the return address. Instead of `arg8 arg 7 ret %rbp arg6` to have something like `ret %rbp arg8 arg7 arg6 ... ` ?